# IE8 Opacity of a div with absolute positioned divs contained inside

Tags: html, css, opacity

Wondering if this is possible: I have a container div, that has opacity set, and inside that div are two(or more) absolute positioned divs. It should make the whole thing transparent,as it does in all browser except IE8 (IE7 even works!)

http://jsfiddle.net/yckQu/6/

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 1):

Almost there.  Just update this one line in the CSS:

```
#opacity, #opacity div {
```

The issue is that when you write *#opacity*, it targets that element, but not its child elements.  Writing it like above corrects that.

http://jsfiddle.net/yckQu/7/

Comment: Hi, not quite the same effect, the two divs have an overlaying opacity (you can see the pink under the hotpink) all other browsers the whole thing is transparent as one object.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following line to the CSS declarations of the inner divs:

```
filter:inherit;
```

This should do the job (it worked for me).

Source:

http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/ie-opacity-inheritance/